# How to create a front facing user sign up, log in and profile pages like FoodGawker.Com

Tags: user-roles, user-access, save-post, user-registration, membership

Title: How to create a front facing user sign up, log in and profile pages like FoodGawker.Com

Body:

Hey everyone!

I'll be as direct and detailed as possible. :)

I want to be able to sign up users and have them have access to their profiles and function/look very much like http://www.foodgawker.com
I need to have a front facing using registration processor with the fields that I predetermine, login & logout fields, and have access to their profile which I need to contain two very basic capabilities:

1. View & change their profile.

And…

1. View & delete their bookmarked posts in a grid like format.

That's it for now. Right now I'm using the following plugin to easily achieve being able to: [User Bookmarks For Wordpress.](http://codecanyon.net/item/user-bookmarks-for-wordpress/544129?WT.ac=search_thumb&WT.seg_1=search_thumb&WT.z_author=cgcookie)

For the purpose of this question I've created a mock account on http://www.foodgawker.com so that you can see visually see what I'm trying to achieve (sorry food gawker!). The login details are:

Username: mockstack
Password: stackoverflow
email: mockupemail@email.com

So the question is how to approach this problem and solve it? I'm a little lost right now and don't really know what to start or what fully needs to be done to achieve this.

I've been around wordpress for while and can program in PHP at a beginner/intermediate level (increasing though). CSS and HTML I'm very strong in and are not a problem.

Thanks for all the help in advance ladies & gents!!

Comment: Sorry, but this is no 1:1 free-support-group therefore please do **not** post log-in details in your questions. (Make sure to read [ask] for more help). As it stands it's quite unclear what you are trying to do and what you have tried so far. Try to [edit] your question and show us (in code) what the problem is, how far you got and where you are stuck. And please don't make your question depend on outgoing links. If the link is gone or has changed (and it will) then the question can't be understood any more. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In another question of yours, you were pointed to the plugin [WP Favorite Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-favorite-posts/), but you seem to have settled with this premium one from Code Canyon.

So, the matter is how to integrate it with a Profile/Registration management plugin, and for that maybe [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) would be a good candidate, as you can customize and add custom code to the following templates:

- login-form.php
- lostpassword-form.php
- profile-form.php
- register-form.php
- resetpass-form.php
- user-panel.php

---

In a side note, maybe this question can be considered [overly broad](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#close), so I urge you to read the full FAQ of this Stack.

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry if it seems like I'm not taking the advice others, I dont' intend it to show that way. I did download and try both plugins, the premium just ended up working out better than the other one. 

I've downloaded and installed Theme My Login and so far it's doing what I need it to do. I'm going to try and see how I can customize the member profile page though, right now it's just a wordpress user panel.

Thank you again for the help!